# opengl bump mapping (normal mapping) problem with VBO and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, vbo, normal-mapping, bump-map

hi i am beginner i am trying to implement bump mapping with vbo and glsl. 
My question is: did i make bump mapping ? if i did why these edges didnt disappear ?

high and low meshes (i used low meshes of course)
[image: high]
[image: low]

[image: and my opengl screen:]

Answer (score 1):

That's not how bump mapping works. Bump mapping adds additional detail to a model, but doesn't change the triangles. You need to render a mooth mesh to make the edges invisible (the normals of a vertex shared by 2 triangles must be the same)

Comment: Additionally the mesh could make use of some smooth shaded normals. But yes the normal map only operates on the faces themselves.

Comment: so i did right ? but this video seems perfect with not smooth low mesh https://youtu.be/ApzVWuPa4A4?t=1113

Comment: @EmreKaya your model is showing flat shading, you might want to adjust the the normals. Notice how the faces all show rigid along the edges?